# Does receiving no reputation for good comments pollute the Answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, up-votes

As you get no reputation for good comments it makes more sense to add your comment as a answer so you might get some reputation. I have seen that done quite often. Answers given that should really be comments.

If some reputation were given for up voted comments it might eliviate some of this?

Comment: After using the comment system for a while now I must agreed with the community

Comment: Related (because they address what should be a comment vs. an answer -- this is *not* a duplicate): [What to do with answers that should be comments, but get deleted?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13893/what-to-do-with-answers-that-should-be-comments-but-get-deleted) and [Please stop posting half answers and dumb advice as comments](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This site is about questions and answers, not comments
Comments are second class citizens, and can be (and are) destroyed without warning. Have something useful? Stick it in a answer.

Related: [Why don't "useful comment" results give reputation?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5431/why-dont-useful-comment-results-give-reputation/5432#5432)

[Reference that I'm not the guy who came up with this.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/david-zaslavsky-moved-comments-no-good#comment3033_1282)

Comment: Ah, so you agree with me. If its not about comments and I want rep I have to add the comment as an answer, so the answer is a comment which is not what this site is about.

Comment: No.   Comments you add as answers will get you *downvotes* and will be deleted eventually.   It's not about the rep,  it's about solving the problem.

Comment: @Doogfar If you have something worthwhile to add to an answer, add it to the answer. You should be able to edit any post on the site (as long as it's not locked).

Comment: Note the "add **to** an answer" as opposed to "add **as** an answer".