# Should I flag comments such as "I agree", "+1 for x", or "I changed x in my post"?

Tags: discussion, comments

Oftentimes I see comments that go along the lines of "+1, really good answer/question!", "I agree, we should do that this way", or "This helped a lot, thanks!".  These comments are encouraging and rewarding to see, but (1) upvotes already provide support/approval from the community and (2) as stated multiple times, including in both in the FAQ and the About section, that Ask Ubuntu is for Q&A, not discussion.  Additionally, I often see "@user, I updated my post."  Should I flag these comments for the sake of keeping Ask Ubuntu cleaner and tidier, or is this not necessary?

Comment: Related on MSO: [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment), [Does a thanking comment like “Thanks for your answer” need to flagged as non-constructive?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169994/does-a-thanking-comment-like-thanks-for-your-answer-need-to-flagged-as-non-con)

Comment: I think "I changed x in my post" is a seperate case. This can be really helpfull if a discussion was started about something and as a result something was changed. Maybe it should be handled the same, but the case is different enough to not just make it the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag for deletions, if they add no value.

[Should users be able to flag comments as obsolete that they have previously upvoted?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3117/should-users-be-able-to-flag-comments-as-obsolete-that-they-have-previously-upvo/3118#3118)

[Why don't "useful comment" results give reputation?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5431/why-dont-useful-comment-results-give-reputation/5432#5432)

[Does receiving no reputation for good comments pollute the Answer?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6271/does-receiving-no-reputation-for-good-comments-pollute-the-answer/6272#6272)

Comment: Please define "value".

Comment: Examples include: adds something useful to the conversation, primarily information regarding the answer. "+1, good post" has no value, that's what up votes are for. "-1, here's why" is ok, because they add value. "This helped a lot, thanks!"  does not, because that's what upvotes are for.

Comment: ^ no value in this comment :)