# If the comment appears to be an answer how should I behave?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I need a bit more extended information on how should I behave in these situations to reduce unanswered amount of questions like:

1. if the comment appears to be an answer provided by me and the user accepts it or the user solves his own question by his own, what are my next steps? I should manage a user to accept my answer and I'm going to write that comment as an answer so he could accept it? And I should to encourage the user to write and accept his own solution if he found his own way out of a problem?
2. How to act if the user accepts the comment as the answer even though it seems like not a common problem and answers to this question may vary and it's more than likely to be about user's specific environmental issues, should it be considered and marked as off-topic?

Because sometimes it happened even to me that the user found his own way out or accepted my as an answer, says: "thanx anyways" which is fine but then just disappears :) and the question seems to be solved but with no exact answer.

and the third I like the functionality of the forum it's fine for me and I have my feature request, it's just my opinion don't judge it :-) maybe somebody held this question before or it's useless but as I know forum can convert answers to comments automatically happened even to me back then when I didn't have enough rep for commenting so the feature basics is that it could convert a comment to an answer only in a case if it's fully accepted as an answer by the owner of the question.

Thank you for reading :-)

Comment: You can't accepts comments as answer, and you shouldn't post a comment which is actually an answer. (Or is this an answer??)

Comment: yes something like this but it's the part of my question... and what if comment was suggested as answer thought it wasn't sure to be an answer 100% before but appeared to be an answer 100% after all that's what confusing

Comment: Related: [Please stop posting half answers and dumb advice as comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281/132594)

Comment: thanks this was somewhat helpful :) can you give an advice on second part of my question `2.`?

Comment: Like Bernard said, you can't accept comments as answers. If it's your comment that didn't really contribute to the solution then simply delete it. If it's someone elses comment [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6382/132594) might be helpfull.

Comment: okay that clarifies a bit more, I'll go somewhere from here :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we probably can summarize it as an answer to our own question. Just don't forget to mention the author of the answer.

Comment: it's just a part of my question :-)

Comment: @JohnnyD. Let me think about the other part of your question. But maybe people can improve the answer also :-)